# How to print first element of subhash in reverse manner Perl

Tags: perl

I want to print the values of every first `$family` reversely, and the first value it prints is the total scalar value in each `$community`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper; 
use Tie::Autotie 'Tie::IxHash';

my @NAMES       = qw(AA AB AC BA BB BC CA CB CC AA AB AC BA BB BC CA CB CC AA AB AC BA BB BC CA CB CC AD CD CE CF BD BE);
my @FAMILIES    = qw(A  A  A  B  B  B  C  C  C  A  A  A  B  B  B  C  C  C  A  A  A  B  B  B  C  C  C  A  C  C  C  B  B);
my @COMMUNITIES = qw(0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  0  2  2  2  1  1);

tie my %community_family_name, 'Tie::IxHash' ;

undef $community_family_name{ $COMMUNITIES[$_] }{ $FAMILIES[$_]}{$NAMES[$_]}
    for 0 .. $#NAMES;

for my $community (keys %community_family_name) {
    my $i = 0;
    for my $family (keys %{ $community_family_name{$community} }) {
        for my $name (keys %{ $community_family_name{$community}{$family} }) {
            $community_family_name{$community}{$family}{$name} = $i++;
        }
    }
}

foreach my $community (sort keys %community_family_name)
{
        foreach my $family (keys %{ $community_family_name{$community} }) 
    {
        foreach my $name (keys %{ $community_family_name{$community}{$family}}) 
        {
            print "[$community] = ";
            print scalar "%{ $community_family_name{$community}";
            print reverse "$community_family_name{$community}{$family}{$name}";
            print " ";
        }
    }
}
print Dumper(\%community_family_name);
```

Current output:

```
[0] = HASH(0x1038c80)0 [0] = HASH(0x1038c80)1 [0] = HASH(0x1038c80)2 [0] = HASH(0x1038c80)3 [0] = HASH(0x1038c80)4 [0] = HASH(0x1038c80)5 [0] = HASH(0x1038c80)6 ...
```

Expected output:

```
[0] = 10 7 4 0
[1] = 11 8 3 0
[2] = 12 6 3 0
```

What is in the `%community_family_name`

```
$VAR1 = {
              '0' => {
                       'A' => {
                                'AA' => [
                                          0
                                        ],
                                'AB' => [
                                          1
                                        ],
                                'AC' => [
                                          2
                                        ],
                                'AD' => [
                                          3
                                        ]
                              },
                       'B' => {
                                'BA' => [
                                          4
                                        ],
                                'BB' => [
                                          5
                                        ],
                                'BC' => [
                                          6
                                        ]
                              },
                       'C' => {
                                'CA' => [
                                          7
                                        ],
                                'CB' => [
                                          8
                                        ],
                                'CC' => [
                                          9
                                        ]
                              }
                     },
               '1' => {
                       'A' => {
                                'AA' => [
                                          0
                                        ],
                                'AB' => [
                                          1
                                        ],
                                'AC' => [
                                          2
                                        ]
                              },
                       'B' => {
                                'BA' => [
                                          3
                                        ],
                                'BB' => [
                                          4
                                        ],
                                'BC' => [
                                          5
                                        ],
                                'BD' => [
                                          6
                                        ],
                                'BE' => [
                                          7
                                        ]
                              },
                       'C' => {
                                'CA' => [
                                          8
                                        ],
                                'CB' => [
                                          9
                                        ],
                                'CC' => [
                                          10
                                        ]
                              }
                     },
               '2' => {
                       'A' => {
                                'AA' => [
                                          0
                                        ],
                                'AB' => [
                                          1
                                        ],
                                'AC' => [
                                          2
                                        ]
                              },
                       'B' => {
                                'BA' => [
                                          3
                                        ],
                                'BB' => [
                                          4
                                        ],
                                'BC' => [
                                          5
                                        ]
                              },
                       'C' => {
                                'CA' => [
                                          6
                                        ],
                                'CB' => [
                                          7
                                        ],
                                'CC' => [
                                          8
                                        ],
                                'CD' => [
                                          9
                                        ],
                                'CE' => [
                                          10
                                        ],
                                'CF' => [
                                          11
                                        ]
                              }
                     }
            };
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output you are currently getting.

Comment: Why are you inserting an array ref with a single element `[$i++]`? Why not just insert the scalar `$i++`? No need to use array for a single element.

Comment: @HåkonHægland, I'm sorry, I forget to update. Now it have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

The first point is your expected result is per `community`, so your `print` functions must stay in the first loop.

The second is you must use `scalar` and `reverse` to arrays, not to scalar value such as double-quoted strings.

```
# Let me shorten your variable name, that's way too long...
my %cfn = %community_family_name;

foreach my $com (sort keys %cfn) {
    # Count up keys in the community
    my $count = map { keys %{$cfn{$com}->{$_}} } keys %{$cfn{$com}};

    my @vals;
    foreach my $family (reverse sort keys %{$cfn{$com}}) {
        my ($first) = sort keys %{$cfn{$com}->{$family}};
        push @vals, @{$cfn{$com}->{$family}->{$first}};
    }

    printf "[%d] = %s", $com, join q{ }, $count, @vals;
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: this is my output by using your script, [0] = 10 6 8 1
[1] = 11 5 7 1
[2] = 12 8 10 1, It was not in order and it started from 1?

Comment: @DanialHaris Could you paste your entire source code somewhere?

Comment: That's because you've changed `%community_family_name` data structure.

Comment: yes because, I don't need to make array ref, because the value is always 1 value. So what should I do?

Comment: If you want to know what the error msg means, see perldiag.  If you want to know Perl data structure, see perldst. If you just want the answer that you don’t aware of, I’m sorry, you came to the wrong place.